# how to update setstate array of object values in react js

Tags: reactjs

**How can I update setChoices object values, Below is an example of my problem:**
I m having choices array of object with values. on setstate(setChoices) want to update the object values.

```
let [choices, setChoices] = useState({
    Choices: [
        {
            OneChoiceWithValueSelected: {
                OptionSelected: '15518',
                Price: 0.9,
                Quantity: 1,
            },
            ProductOptionId: 5712,
        },
    ],
    Note: 'test message',
    ProductId: 6,
    Quantity: 1,
    StoreId: '6',
    TableId: 0,
});

const demo = () => {
    setChoices({
        Choices: [
            {
                OneChoiceWithValueSelected: {
                    OptionSelected: '15518',
                    Price: 100,
                    Quantity: 12,
                },
                ProductOptionId: 5712,
            },
        ],
        Note: 'its a new message',
        ProductId: 6,
        Quantity: 10,
        StoreId: '10',
        TableId: 0,
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(choices));
};

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={demo}>test</button>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to you're state structure, you have to update the setChoices part as follows

```
const demo = () => {
    setChoices({
        Choices[0].OneChoiceWithValueSelected.OptionSelected: '15518',
        Choices[0].OneChoiceWithValueSelected.Price: 100,
        Choices[0].OneChoiceWithValueSelected.Quantity: 12,
        Choices[0].ProductOptionId: 5712,
        Note: 'its a new message',
        ProductId: 6,
        Quantity: 10,
        StoreId: '10',
        TableId: 0
    })
    alert(JSON.stringify(choices))
}
```

you have to access the 0th array element to update it's attributes, because the OneChoiceWithValueSelected object is the first element of the Choices array and then use object notation to access others.

Comment: Will check if anything will comment again, thank you